# React Next js Fails At popperjs module

Tags: reactjs, next.js, popperjs

I have a next js project for a while. For sometime the build is ok, until I clean install the node module from scratch.

Now I got an error when ever try to build.

> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Package path ./lib/enums is not exported from package {PROEJCT_PATH}\node_modules@popperjs\core (see exports field in {PROEJCT_PATH}\node_modules@popperjs\core\package.json)

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

here are my package json

**package json main project**

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "TODO: Give a short introduction of your project. Let this section explain the objectives or the motivation behind this project.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci",
    "local": "next dev -p 2001",
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "npx next telemetry disable && next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "start_local": "node server.js",
    "ri": "npm install && npm run dev",
    "u-lib": "npm remove vesta-vnext-react-library"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Shopify",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-demo-app-node-react/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-demo-app-node-react#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@azure/identity": "1.3.0",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "2.15.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "1.0.0",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.15.1",
    "@koa/cors": "3.1.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "4.0.0-alpha.23",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "1.13.0",
    "D": "1.0.0",
    "async-retry": "1.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "clsx": "1.1.1",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "filter-objects": "2.1.1",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "formidable": "^1.2.2",
    "g": "2.0.1",
    "hamburger-react": "2.4.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "3.0.0",
    "joi": "17.4.0",
    "joi-password-complexity": "5.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.6.0",
    "js-cookie": "2.2.1",
    "koa": "2.13.0",
    "koa-router": "10.0.0",
    "koa-session": "6.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
    "map": "1.0.1",
    "material-table": "1.57.2",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "msal": "1.4.4",
    "next": "^11.1.2",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^8.0.0",
    "nextjs-cors": "^1.0.5",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.1",
    "powerbi-client-react": "1.3.0",
    "progressbar.js": "1.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.4.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "2.0.4",
    "react-cookie": "4.0.3",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-d3-speedometer": "1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draggable": "4.4.3",
    "react-dropzone": "11.3.2",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "6.14.1",
    "react-icons": "4.1.0",
    "react-idle-timer": "4.5.4",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "0.4.4",
    "react-select": "4.3.0",
    "sass": "1.29.0",
    "store-js": "2.0.4",
    "tmp": "^0.2.1",
    "my-library": "file:my-library-0.5.0.tgz"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.1.3",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.5",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.168",
    "@types/node": "14.14.10",
    "@types/react-csv": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.14.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.21.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jest-ts-auto-mock": "2.0.0",
    "next-page-tester": "0.24.1",
    "react-date-range": "^1.1.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "ts-auto-mock": "3.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.5.5",
    "ttypescript": "1.5.12",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  }
}
```

**package json my-library**

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "description": "A library that has usable components for vNext project",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "12.5.0",
    "@date-io/moment": "1.3.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.14",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.3.10",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "13.0.0",
    "@types/react-phone-number-input": "3.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "5.0.1",
    "jquery": "3.6.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "papaparse": "5.3.1",
    "precss": "4.0.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "2.0.4",
    "react-data-table-component": "6.11.5",
    "react-date-range": "1.1.3",
    "react-dropzone": "11.3.2",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-phone-input": "^1.2.1",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.14.0",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.25",
    "styled-components": "5.0.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "12.5.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.2",
    "@date-io/moment": "1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "13.0.0",
    "precss": "4.0.0",
    "react-dropzone": "11.3.2",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.6.0",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-date-range": "1.1.3",
    "react-data-table-component": "6.11.5",
    "styled-components": "5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "ts-build": "tsc --project ./ --module commonjs",
    "b-lib": "rollup -c && npm pack",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.14.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.13.13",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "19.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "2.0.6",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "8.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "6.2.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.2.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "6.2.9",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "6.2.9",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "3.1.7",
    "@storybook/react": "6.2.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.15",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.170",
    "@types/node": "12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.2.6",
    "axios": "0.21.1",
    "date-fns": "2.0.0-beta.5",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "postcss": "8.3.0",
    "postcss-import": "14.0.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-advanced-form": "1.7.2",
    "react-advanced-form-addons": "1.3.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.6.0",
    "react-checkbox-tree": "1.6.0",
    "react-data-table-component": "6.11.5",
    "react-date-range": "1.1.3",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "rollup": "2.50.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-import-css": "2.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "2.6.1",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "7.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "0.30.0",
    "tsc": "2.0.3",
    "tslib": "2.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.2.4",
    "web-vitals": "1.0.1"
  },
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "typescript": {
    "definition": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "reactDocgen": "none"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "__"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the imports for the file that is throwing that error.

Comment: I dont have a file ts/js that directly uses popperjs

Comment: Can you post your redacted `package.json`?

Comment: @John I already updated question with package.json